# How do I return a list with only one stringed element? Python

Tags: python, string, list

```
from lab10_classes import Pharmacy

def costliest_drug(pharmacy):
    drug_list = []
    cost_list = []
    drug_list3 = []
    most_expensive = 0

    for name in pharmacy.inventory:
        drug_list.append(name)

    for key in pharmacy.unit_prices and pharmacy.inventory:
        cost1 = pharmacy.unit_prices[key]
        cost2 = pharmacy.inventory[key]
        cost = cost1 * cost2
        cost_list.append(cost)

    for i in range(len(cost_list)):
        if cost_list[i] > most_expensive:
            most_expensive = cost_list[i]
            drug_list3.append(drug_list[i])
        continue

    return drug_list3[len(drug_list3)-1]
```

My return value is correct, it is the word, 'Hydrochlorothiazide'; and this is what my return value looks like:

> Hydrochlorothiazide

However, I need my return value to look like this:

> [’Hydrochlorothiazide’]

It needs to be a string inside a list. How do i do that?

Comment: Create a list append result to list and return list?!

Comment: holy cow... I wasted 2 hours reading up on lambda, map, filter, and reduce. After researching and testing in vain, I finally came to stackoverflow just to get humiliated. FML

Comment: There is no need for `len` function to access the last element of a list. It can simply be retrieved by `drug_list3[-1]`.

Comment: that is true, I will fix it right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list on the go by using the square brackets. So in your case:

```
 return [drug_list3[len(drug_list3)-1]]
```

should do the trick. Also to make a string you can use `str()`.